# How to deal with information that arrives null? - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm getting null information from a web api. If a single information is null, the error will occur:

> Error: Exception: NoSuchMethodError: '[]'
> Dynamic call of null.
> Receiver: null
> Arguments: ["address"]

I declared this information in the model like this:

```
final String? address;

..
address: json['data1']['data2'][0]['data3']['address'][0]
```

I tried to do something like:

> address: json['data1']['data2'][0]['data3']['address'][0].isEmpty
> ? ''
> : json['data1']['data2'][0]['data3']['address'][0],

But it does not work.

**I appreciate if anyone can help me analyze it!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to anticipate the `null` values and handle each case as needed.

For instance, if a null value is not accepted at all, you could wrap the code in `throw ... catch` statement then throw an error -- e.g.`Missing Data` and handle that error.

If having a `null` value is fine, you can use the `null` aware operator `?` (or a nested if-statements if you prefer that). For example, assuming the value is a String, you could do something like this:

```dart
final String? myValue = json['data1']?['data2']?[0]?['data3']?['address']?[0];
```

Though, keep in mind if you're accessing a list by index, you still can get a `RangeError` if the index is out of range or if the list is empty. In such case you may need to split the process in a separate method and inspect each part separately such as:

```dart
String? extractValue(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  final firstList = json['data1']?['data2'];
  if (firstList is List && firstList.isNotEmpty) {
    final innerList = firstList[0]['data3']?['address'];
    if (innerList is List && innerList.isNotEmpty) {
      return innerList[0];
    }
  }
  return null; // or return a default value or throw an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle such arguments ( arguments that give you null value) like this.
Let's say there's a variable a and there's a possibility that it'll give a null value, you can give it a default value.
For example:
There is a  variable 'a', which is your data source.

```
String name = a ?? "This is not a null value";
```

The ?? would check if the value is null or not. If it's null, it would assign the value that you provided, otherwise it would keep the existing one.